# How do I restore a site from backup

Tags: craft3, back-up

I broke permissions in a critical craft install. My solution was to install a new version of the craft, move all of the templates from the old site to the new site and restore the MySQL database.

Problem is that craft wants to run the setup installer.

Can anyone provide me a quick recipe for restoring a craft3 site from backups? I have the database and all of the assets/templates etc.

Comment: If you're installing a new version does that not require the setup installer to run?

Comment: Tangental, but this may help you in the future: https://nystudio107.com/blog/mitigating-disaster-via-website-backups

Answer (score 2):

If you've copied the Craft files to a new place on the server, then you can either leave the database connection information the same and have it keep on pointing to the current database instance, or edit `craft/config/db.php` (or your `.env` file if that's how you're setup) to point to a new database instance.

If the new one is a blank database, the Craft installer will want to run.  If you want a copy of your old database on the new one, you'll need to do a database dump from the old one and restore it to the new one.  If you do the latter and you're still getting Craft to prompt to run the installer, then there is something wrong with the database connection settings between Craft/PHP and the database and those should be adjusted.